# LinkedIn API people company

Tags: api, linkedin-api

I would like to show the people numbers of a company. For that I display a result of a search.

I got a numResult but this number is not the real number of the company

```
IN.API.PeopleSearch()
.fields("id", "firstName", "lastName", "headline", "pictureUrl","location","public-profile-url")
.params({
"company-name": "Google",
"current-company": true,
"count": 8,
})
.result(function(result, metadata) {
setSearchResults(result, metadata);
});
}
```

Then I have `result.numResults` who is not the good number of the company. Someone has an idea?

I guess this is the number of the company about the user when he is connected.

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve specifics about companies, including the company size, from the [Company API](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/company-lookup-api-and-fields). The specific field that contains the size range for the company is `employee-count-range`.

In terms of accessing the data via the JavaScript API, consider using the [`IN.API.Raw()`](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/inapiraw) method.